# SQL - recursive query to unroll a table

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I am sorry for the supidity of this question, but i am new to SQL. I have the following table:

---------- Table countries -----------

REGION - Country - CITY

EMEA - Italy - Rome

EMEA - Italy - Florence

EMEA - SPAIN - Madrid

APJ - Japan - Tokio

APJ - Japan - Hiroshima

APJ - China - Bejin

I would have to unroll it using recursive queries and obtain what follows:

EMEA

Italy

Rome

Florence

SPAIN

Madrid

APJ

Japan

Tokio

Hiroshima

China

Bejin

I have no idea where to start.. any hints?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: So you have table with 3 columns and you want to select all 3 columns into one column?

Comment: Yes, i do want to unwrap the table into a unique list. that follows the following structure:
Region1--> Country1--> all countries of country 1--> country 2 --> all countries of country 2.... --> Region 2 --> and so forth and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get something like this query:

```
with united AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        REGION col,
        1 rnk, --Region goes before Countries and Cities
        REGION,
        null Country --we need only one appearance for each Region
        FROM your_table
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Country,
        2,
        REGION,
        Country 
        FROM your_table
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        CITY,
        3,
        REGION,
        Country  
        FROM your_table
)
select col 
FROM united
ORDER BY REGION,Country,rnk
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06cb1/1/0)

But there is no recursion.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that returns the expected result. However there is no recursion, which is the first topic i am facing now.
I have also tried to select distinct subsets and to use pointers, but i do not think to be the best way with SQL.